# source code: WP_INSTALLING vs. WP_SETUP_CONFIG in setup-config.php

Tags: code, customization

I am trying to make sense of the wordpress installation process.
The file `setup-config.php` under `wp-admin` has the following.
I want to know what the difference is between these two variables,
why both are needed, and what exactly the `WP_SETUP_CONFIG` boolean
indicates.

```
/**
 * We are installing.
 */
define('WP_INSTALLING', true);

/**
 * We are blissfully unaware of anything.
 */
define('WP_SETUP_CONFIG', true);
```

When I do a search in Aptana with CTRL-H I can see that `WP_INSTALLING` is
referebced in quite a few files and `WP_SETUP_CONFIG` in just a few. What
does we are blissfully unaware of anything mean? That we don't have a
`wp-config.php` file or what?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the dark and pretty much undocumented heart of WordPress. The comment kind of reads like a inside joke, but probably isn't meant to be one. I've found this little piece of information »*Will be defined if WordPress will be installed or configured.*« [here](http://wpengineer.com/2382/wordpress-constants-overview/#WP_SETUP_CONFIG). And fittingly the constant is part of an gist called [WordPress constants that should have never been constants](https://gist.github.com/tierra/7095615). Aside from that I unfortunately can't help you further, as I do not know more about it.

Comment: Thank you. Your comments have been helpful, although I still don't understand why we need to treat installation and configuration separately and why we need both constants. Thanks.

Comment: I kind of have to guess here, because it didn't inspect it further, but I'm assuming it's because you can install with a pre-configured `wp-config.php` ready or you install and create the `wp-config.php` via the [installation script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Step_3:_Set_up_wp-config.php).

Comment: Also `WP_INSTALLING` will be defined when installing/updating themes/plugins/translations.